# Rescue Errors and redirect in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I want to redirect a user when errors are raised but the code below the rescue seem to be called after redirect.  What is the difference between redirect and return? Or what is happening?

in the user model:

```
 def self.find_by_credentials(user_name,password)
    user = User.find_by_user_name(user_name)
    msg = 'User Not Found'
    raise StandardError, msg unless user
    msg = 'Invalid Login'
    raise StandardError, msg unless user.is_password?(password)

    user
  end
```

in the session controller:

```
def create
    begin
      user = User.find_by_credentials(
        params[:user][:user_name],
        params[:user][:password]
      )

    rescue StandardError => e
      flash.now[:errors] = e.message
      redirect_to new_user_url
    end

    login_user!(user)
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking MrDanA's advice I've found a style I feel comfortable with and works.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    begin
      @user = User.authenticate!(
        params[:user]
      )
      redirect_to root_url
    rescue StandardError => e
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid Login"
      render :new
    end
  end
```

This way I can leave the authentication logic in the user model and the bang will let the errors decide how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a return at the end of the rescue fixed this

```
def create
    begin
      user = User.find_by_credentials(
        params[:user][:user_name],
        params[:user][:password]
      )

    rescue StandardError => e
      flash.now[:errors] = e.message
      redirect_to new_user_url
      return #this fixed it
    end

    login_user!(user)
  end
```

Comment: `redirect_to` does not cause the method to stop running and start redirecting. `return` is a Ruby keyword that does stop the method. In this case, what you should have done is put the `login_user!(user)` part within the `begin` because that's the only time it should happen - this gives you better program control/flow instead of having a random `return` in the middle of your method.